# iMessage App - iOS 10 localParticipantIdentifier.UUIDString does not translate in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, imessage

Below is a snippet showing adding a subcaption to a previously created MSMessage. Upon running in the simulator, the string prefixed with $ does not translate to the contact name as expected.

Bug in my code?

```
MSMessageTemplateLayout *templateLayout = [[MSMessageTemplateLayout alloc] init];
NSString *messageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Challenged by $%@", 
                                                     currentConversation.localParticipantIdentifier.UUIDString];  
[templateLayout setSubcaption:messageText];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open radar for it: https://openradar.appspot.com/26877873

Comment: Thanks.. so its a valid bug..? I've raised another ticket on programatically adding .apng if you stumble across that one too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957174/imessage-apps-programatically-create-animated-sticker-from-apng

Comment: Seems so. I have the same behavior here.